# How to append to variable ONLY if string exists in another file?

Tags: powershell, powershell-core

I have the following code which is working as expected :

```
Try {
    Foreach($Dir In $Dirs){
        Foreach($File in $Files) {
            $EntitySiteList +=  Import-Csv "$Dir$File" -Header Entity, Site | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Select Entity, Site| Sort-Object Entity, Site -Unique
        }
    }
}
Catch {
    Write-Host "Encountered the following error : $($Error[0])"
    exit 1
}
```

It's reading 1 or more files and populating/appending $EntitySiteList variable with Entity & Site values.  I need to add to this logic and append Site, Entity values IF the Site value exists in a Master file (i.e. Site_Master.csv).

Is that possible?

Answer (score 1):

Read the values from the master file into a `[HashSet[string]]`, then use `Where-Object` to filter the CSV entries:

```
# populate site name set
$sites = [System.Collections.Generic.HashSet[string]]::new()
Import-Csv .\Site_Master.csv |ForEach-Object {
  [void]$sites.Add($_.Site)
}

try {
    $EntitySiteList = foreach($Dir in $Dirs){
        foreach($File in $Files) {
            Import-Csv "$Dir$File" -Header Entity, Site | Select-Object Entity, Site -Skip 1 |Where-Object { $sites.Contains($_.Site) } |Sort-Object Entity, Site -Unique
        }
    }
}
catch {
    Write-Host "Encountered the following error : $($Error[0])"
    exit 1
}
```

Comment: Mathias R. Jessen, that worked wonderfully! Thank so much!